# Slant product in homology/cohomology - is it an instance of dinaturality? Spanier

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading the (increasingly difficult) book by Spanier. He gives an argument that the slant product is natural with respect to a category of subspaces $(A,B)$ of a fixed space $X$ by appeal to a dinaturality theorem. I cannot follow it, as something seems amiss to me with covariance/contravariance of the maps involved.

Let the slant product 
$$H^n((X,A)\times (Y,B);G) \otimes H_q(Y,B;G')\to H^{n-q}(X,A;G\otimes G')$$
be defined as follows: given a cocycle $[f]$ and a cycle $[c'\otimes g']$ we form the linear functional on $\Delta(X)/\Delta(A)_q$ into $G\otimes G'$ that sends $c$ to $f(c\otimes c')\otimes g'$. One then checks that this is all well defined and so on.

Spanier states a dinaturality theorem as follows: given $f: (X,A)\to (X',A')$ and $g: (Y,B)\to (Y', B')$  we have a commutative diagram[image]

He then says we should be able to appeal to this theorem to derive a commutative diagram
[image]

But I don't understand why this should be the case. I have tried to set up the argument but I only get
[image]
and then I seem to be unable to fill in the rest of the diagram due to some covariance/contravariance issues with $i$ and $j$. What am I missing here?